# Passing arguments to Docker entry point

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I'm having difficulty getting my docker image execute its entry point with the arguments I'm specifying.

In my docker file I have the following:

```
...
EXPOSE 8123
WORKDIR /bin_vts
VOLUME /bin_vts
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin_vts/vts", "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')", "8123"]
```

I want my program to take as an argument the output of `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'`(an ip address). I have tested this on my local machine and it works fine when I use `/bin_vts/vts $(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}') 8123`

However when I use this in docker my program tells me that I'm passing "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')" instead of the expected ip address.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried using a script but that says permission denied. This is getting deployed to ECS using Fargate and I tried it locally as well and in both places it fails.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried an entrypoint of /bin/bash like this?

```ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/bin_vts/vts", "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')", "8123"]```

I think the issue is that your argument is being taken as a literal; if you run it through bash first you might be able to pass the correct final parameter to the program.

Comment: Nothing you do in your Dockerfile can cause commands to be executed on the host; even if you use the [shell form of `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) that `hostname` command will be executed in the container.

Comment: @dominique120 I'm glad! I just posted it as an answer as well -- would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/bin_vts/vts", "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')", "8123"]
```

The original entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin_vts/vts", "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')", "8123"]
```

is passing the literal argument `$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')` to `vts`. By using bash, you can evaluate the argument before passing it to `vts`.